# Evento TEXTAREA Redimensionamento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero uma forma de pegar o evento do textArea quando ele for clicado na sua seta de redimensionamento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o evento `mousemove` você pode detectar quando o `textarea` for redimensionado armazenando em variáveis as dimensões atuais:

```js
var largura = $("textarea").width();
var altura = $("textarea").height();
$("textarea").on("mousemove", function(){

    var larg_atual = $(this).width();
    var altu_atual = $(this).height();

    if(larg_atual != largura || altu_atual != altura){
        largura = larg_atual;
        altura = altu_atual;
        console.log("Tamanho alterado");
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```